# Why do I get a permission denied error while running my script in Python IDLE as administrator?

Tags: python, windows, web-scraping, permissions, user-permissions

I have a web scraping script that is otherwise 100% functional. It is pointed at a website, stores attributes, paginates, and *should* be storing images for ConvNet processing, but I get an "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied [directory]" - when I comment out the image storage portion of the script, everything else works great.

I've tried changing from open(directory, 'wb') to urllib.request.urlopne(url) as response, open(directory,' 'wb') but of course the permission issue isn't solved.

I've run the program in CMD as admin, I've run the program directly through Python IDLE as admin, I've given permission to myself (the run as user) as well as NETWORK SERVICES and LOCAL SERVICE to the root of the storage drive, but I still receive a permission denied error.

Some unique behavior that I've observed; it creates a folder where an image should be stored, AND throws a permission denied error. The level at which the folder is created is where the image should be. The folder takes the name of the image. To eliminate variables, I tried feeding in a static string for the file name, and I still get permission denied. The folder is named "EFake.jpg", for example, when that folder should be a retrieved image in .jpg format. I've searched far and wide for a resolution to this issue, I feel like I've tried everything, apologies if I'm missing the obvious.

The entry point:

```
  if items.get('reference_number'):
            download_img_to_disk(brand, listing_url_retrieve_id, items['entry_logo'], items.get('reference_number'))
        else:
            download_img_to_disk(brand, listing_url_retrieve_id, items['entry_logo'])

#The function: 

def download_img_to_disk(brand, name, url, reference_number='uncatogrized'):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    directory = "Z:\Storage\\"+str(brand)+"\\"+str(reference_number)+"\\"+name+'.jpg'
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(directory, 'wb') as out_file:
        data = response.read()
        out_file.write(data)
    return "File Downloaded.."
```

I expect "Z:\Storage\"+str(brand)+"\"+str(reference_number)+"\"+name+'.jpg' to be an actual .jpg stored, but it's a folder named name+'.jpg' and I receive the "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied [directory]" error message simultaneously. I feel like the datatype is wrong, the level at which the .jpg should be stored is wrong... I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Your code clearly creates a directory named `name+'.jpg'`. Can you not see that? The permission error is from trying to open a directory as a regular file. It has nothing to do with admin access.

Comment: use `print(directory)` to see what you have in variable. It is path with filename at the end. You can't use it to create directory because it will create directory `name+".jpg"`

Comment: I took out the +"\\"+name+'.jpg' from directory, and it prints the correct directory for which the image should be stored. It is then referenced with my urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(directory, 'wb') and I still receive the permission issue. I feel as though I'm pointing it to a file directory, and asking it to store an image